# How can I synchronize a block/method in Java while using parallel TestNG methods?

Tags: java, multithreading, junit, synchronization, testng

Let's say I have the following snippet (TestNG):

```
package com.parallel;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestParallelOne {

    @Test
    public void testCaseOne() {
        //Printing Id of the thread on using which test method got executed
        System.out.println("Test Case One with Thread Id:- "
                + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        test();
    }

    @Test
    public void testCaseTwo() {
        ////Printing Id of the thread on using which test method got executed
        System.out.println("Test Case two with Thread Id:- "
                + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        test();
    }

    public synchronized void test()
    {
        for(int i =0; < 10; i++) System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

and the following suite.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Parallel test suite" parallel="methods" thread-count="2">
  <test name="Regression 1">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.parallel.TestParallelOne"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

My expectations are that the tests will run parallel but the first one that acquires a lock will hold it until it finishes the method (same expectation with a synchronized block), but the synchronized keyword is completely ignored...
What's the problem here? The synchronized method solution is the BEST solution for my particular case but it seems I am missing something with TestNG?

Answer (score 0):

try to take a lock on static object

package com.parallel;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestParallelOne{

```
private static String LOCK = "lock";

@Test
public void testCaseOne() {
    System.out.println("Test Case One with Thread Id:- "  + 
    Thread.currentThread().getId());
    test();
}

@Test
public void testCaseTwo() {
    System.out.println("Test Case two with Thread Id:- "
            + Thread.currentThread().getId());
    test();
}

public void test()
{
    synchronized(LOCK){
    for(int i =0; < 10; i++) System.out.println(i);
  }
}
```

}

Comment: Hm yeah, I will give it a try tomorrow, it should work with a static object in the test class.